# Connect to localhost development server in docker bridge network

Tags: nginx, docker

Within a docker container I have a development server running that runs at:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

Via nginx I am trying to make a request to this server:

**nginx.conf**

```
upstream service_rest {
    server restapi:8000;
}

server {

    location /rest/ {
        proxy_pass http://service_rest;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

My understanding would be this:

1. When I type localhost:9000/rest/ (port 9000 is exposed to my host machine and mapped to the nginx docker service) nginx looks upstream to the service_rest server on port 8000 --> this part works
2. service_rest:8000 automatically "knows" that the request is for the development server running on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` inside the container

Here is the problem, though: I don't think the requests are ever passed to the server running on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

I recieve the following message as a log:

> nginx_1     | 2019/05/11 07:49:06 [error] 6#6: *1 connect() failed
>   (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client:
>   192.168.32.1, server: , request: "GET /rest/admin/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.32.2:8000/rest/admin/", host:
>   "localhost:9000"

`http://192.168.32.2:8000/rest/admin/` (ip of container in bridge network) obviously is not equal to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` even though I sort of thought they were?

**I am quite new to docker and nginx and a little confused about this. Can you guys help?**

Answer (score 0):

For interested parties:

The trick was to not have the development server run on localhost but instead on:

```
0.0.0.0:8000
```